# how to acess guice session scope in jsp using el

Tags: jsp, guice

I am new to guice DI Framework
In Spring we can access the session scope variable using el

```
sessionScope['scopedTarget.sessionService'].loggedUser
```

But how can I do this in guice?

Answer (score 1):

If you choose to use [Guice's Servlet extension](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Servlets), you should be able to bind an HttpSession or Provider<HttpSession> automatically.

In your class, you would put something like this:

```
private final MyDependency dependency;
private final Provider<HttpSession> sessionProvider;

@Inject
public MyClass(MyDependency dependency, Provider<HttpSession> sessionProvider) {
  this.dependency = dependency;
  this.sessionProvider = sessionProvider;
}

void callMyService() {
  HttpSession session = sessionProvider.get();
  String myValue = (String) session.get("value");
  // ...
}
```

Providers are built-in interfaces that let you get fresh instances from the injector. If class Foo is bound, you can always inject Provider<Foo> without any additional work. Here, injecting a Provider is a good idea, because the class you're writing may live longer than any given session.